# Zend framework installation error

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

I am installing Zend framework in Ubuntu 12.04.  When I try to create a new project using the command `zf create project zf_test` it gives this error:

> Testing Note: PHPUnit was not found in your include_path, therefore no
>   testing actions will be created.

I need to know what was that message and how to solve this.

Comment: This is not programming question...

Comment: Is it necessary to ask only programming question. I don't see any problem with asking questions about programming tools or environment.

Comment: If you are not going to write tests with **PHPUnit**, just ignore it. Else install and configure PHPUnit. _FYI_ PHPUnit is the default test library for writing unit tests against PHP. What this really means to you is that _Zend_Tool_ will not auto generate test stubs for your application in the _/tests_ directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to install PHPUnit in your system. Please follow this tutorial(it is for ubuntu 11.04 but also it works in later versions) http://www.giocc.com/installing-phpunit-on-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal.html

Comment: @EnamulHaque If the answer worked for you, it's better to accept the answer.